# Just give me the words between the ""

Tags: regex, awk

I have text lines like this

```
blahblah"word1"blahblah"word2"blahblah"word3"
```

I only want the text between the quotes and without the quotes.  I could do an awk and us the " as a separator.  And then get every second match.  However, is there any way I can just use awk (or another command) to return words between sets of quotes?  so I'd get back word1, word2, word3?

Thanks,

Comment: Are quotes always in pairs; are they adjacent to the word; is it always a single word (no white space); is there always white space next to the "outside" of the double quote?

Comment: I don't get it. You described how you can do what you want with awk and then asked how to do what you want with awk. Huh?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
echo 'blahblah"word1"blahblah"word2"blahblah"word3"' | perl -ne 'print map("$_\n", m/"([^"]*)"/g)'
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends which language you're using, but the regular expression to do this would be:

```
(?<=^(("[^"]*){2})*")[^"]+(?=")
```

That example will match everything between "s. if you want it to match only words between "s, use:

```
(?<=^(("[^"]*){2})*")\b+(?=")
```

The main difference is with the second example, spaces and most special characters will not be allowed. With the first example, all characters except for "s will be allowed between the "s. That includes new lines.

Comment: Note - entering this regex into most languages (or shells) is going to require some thought because of the `"`s ... Could you give a working example of how to use this?

Comment: @Floris , In C#, if you import System.Text.RegularExpressions, you could say:

     MatchCollection foobar = new Regex("(?<=^((\"[^\"]*){2})*\")\b+(?=\")").Matches(inputString);

Comment: It looks correct - create a live demo on rubular or similar to show it works

Comment: Ruby doesn't like it but (?<=^[^"]*(("[^"]*){2})*")[a-z]+(?=") works in visual studio

Answer (score 1):

Non-robust, but fun:

```
sed -E 's/(^|")[^"]*("|$)/ /g'
```